# I would like to insert datetime into SQL table as 13 digit number by sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, casting

The table column `assignedDate` value is a 13 digit number like `1536346340276`, format is `2014-12-31 15:17:24.736`

Once I insert the data with query

```
INSERT INTO Test (id, assignedDate)
VALUES (1, (SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-31 15:17:24.736') AS NUMERIC)))
```

The result is `42003`

How to convert 13 digit number using by SQL query?

Comment: which DBMS? (e.g mssql, mysql..)

Comment: You might be able to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date)` for seconds, or multiply UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) by 1000 for milliseconds.

Comment: What is the conversion from 1536346340276 to 2014-12-31 15:17:24.736?  This is not a Unix timestamp.

Comment: This is MS sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume `1536346340276` doesn't actually translate to `2014-12-31 15:17:24.736`, but that the 13 digit number is simply an example of the data currently in the table and that the date provided is an example of how the input format will be, it looks like it could actually be Unix time

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, 1536346340276/1000 ,'1970/1/1')          -- is 2018-09-07 18:52:20.000
SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, getdate()), GETDATE()     -- is 1537195014053 at 2018-09-17 14:36:54.053
```

If you're on SQL Server 2016 or higher, the new insert would look like:

```
INSERT INTO Test (id, assignedDate)
VALUES (1, (SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, getdate())))
```